# Rsync directories into a flatter structure

Tags: linux, file, unix, rsync

I'm looking for a way to flatten directories from a /year/month/day/directory format to just /directory via rsync

The source directories, containing data files, are formatted like this:

/year/month/day/round-number/files

Source:

```
/2018/06/01/round-1111/(files)
/2018/06/01/round-1112/(etc)
/2018/06/01/round-1113

/2018/06/02/round-1114
/2018/06/02/round-1115
/2018/06/02/round-1116

/2018/06/03/round-1117
/2018/06/03/round-1118
/2018/06/03/round-1119
```

I need them to come out like this at the Destination:

```
/round-1111/(files)
/round-1112/(etc)
/round-1113
/round-1114
/round-1115
/round-1116
/round-1117
/round-1118
/round-1119
```

The command I'm using right now is basically "rsync -a source destination"
I'd like to keep the processing load of this command low, as it needs to run frequently while also not disturbing the source server too much.

Comment: You'll have to perform this move/rename either before or after the rsync. There is no way to rename or restructure files with rsync.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to flatten it to 1 directory containing the round directories as described above, on the destination server? - and I'm being told by my developer that they need the files flattened for a programming project, apparently the language doesn't work well with nested subdirectories.